# Images in drawable folder is not recognized android

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I have using many images in drawable folder , with no problem . But suddenly there was a problem with this drawable folder . I have put icon images for **"Anniversary Wedding Stone"** which was extracted from `.pdf file` . I am not able to use these images anyway

Cannot use in xml file as `android:src="@drawable/"`

Cannot use in `Activity class as R.drawable`

`id` is not generated in `R.java`

Please suggest

Comment: might be your images name contains invalid characters.

Comment: Your image name doesn't contain spaces

Comment: Invalid characters ?? . I can view images like a normal one

Comment: what is your image name??post it

Comment: @kalyan pvs ----- image name is "paper" with png extension

Comment: @karthik is remaining images are available??

Comment: @kalyan pvs --- all icons extracted from .pdf file in not recognized . I even tried converting to .png online . nothing worked.. After a lot of search I got these icons ,but no use

Comment: is your R.java file generaterd for other images and layouts??

Comment: @kalyan pvs --no , thats the main problem . Many time i tried cleaning the project , restarted eclipse, nothing worked.

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: @karthik R.java file is not generated when the naming convention are wrong or your layout files contains any errors checkout you res folder for all namings.

Comment: If there is naming error in my project , then it wont run ..It runs with other icon names

Comment: @kalyan pvs -- I just found that any new image added is not recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your effort..

I solved my problem . I always used to copy the images to drawable folder manually , but this time I copied the images through the project in eclipse, it worked..